# How to Edit a Java Object from Another Class With Ease

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin

I'm coming from Python whereby I just passed `self` and I could edit the objects that way.

So I have some code:

```
public void initLayout() {
        DockLayoutPanel layout = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.PC);
        layout.addNorth(new HTML(" v0.1"), 2);
        layout.addSouth(new HTML("Footer"), 2);
        layout.addWest(new HTML(""), 2);
        layout.add(new HTML("center"));
        RootLayoutPanel rootLayout = RootLayoutPanel.get();
        rootLayout.add(layout);
    }
```

This sets out the layout of the panel I'm using. I now want to easily edit/add to parts of these panels with ease. So for example in another method:

```
private void initPanel() {
        rootlayout.add(some_new_component);

    }
```

Or even in the future add to scroll bars etc. I know I could create a method which functioned in a way that I can pass it variables to add all the data now, but I want it to be more flexible in that I want to change things later.

Comment: In your RootLayoutPanel class, maybe you could use a data structure like a Map? This would allow you to add new components with a key, value pair to be able to access different components with different layouts.

Comment: A data structure will not solve access problems.

Comment: Python - `self.rootlayout.add(newContent)`, I'd like to know if there is any similar method I can use in Java

Comment: You can pass an instance of an object with this

Comment: But using `this` is usually unnecessary (the most common reason for it is that you have a method parameter with the same name as a field). It's really unclear what you're trying to accomplish here, but generally speaking, you save references to items you'll need to grab in the future (such as text boxes) and don't save reference to items you won't care about (such as many layout containers).

Comment: I'm creating an object which happens to be a panel, then I want to be able to access this panel later and change parameters of it. I don't know if I'll need a text box in it later, hence why I don't want to reference items now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the keyword:

```
this
```

Referring to your comment, in Java you would write:

```
this.rootlayout.add(newContent);
```

the keyword "this" refers to the current object.

Comment: So simple. Thankyou =) Always a few hurdles when learning a new language

Comment: As someone mentioned in comments above, you can leave out the this keyword from the code (Java compiler takes care of that, and you could just write rootlayout.add(newContent); -- However, this takes away readability of your code, and it is preferred to use the this keyword.